# Exotic Derivatives Model Calibration

Tags: exotics

Suppose if we will like to price an exotic option with a model,we calibrate them to natural hedging instruments that are available in the market.  Do we use all the instruments as hedge or only a portion of them?

Comment: Typically you require all strikes, but only instruments with expires less than or equal to that of the exotic.